# how to work with an address that has $ in its path in python

Tags: python, windows, file, path

Alert! it is beginner level question.

I want to write a python code that saves a file in a location that is like this:

\147.134.45.32\d$\output\mil

When I paste it in the address bar of folder of windows, it opens the location but when I use the same address in my python code it throws error:

```
workplace = ("\\147.134.45.32\d$\output\mil/" + folder + "/")

if not os.path.exists(workplace):
    os.mkdir(workplace)
```

How should I change this path to work?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace (the error you get) so that we know which line is causing the error and exactly what python's complaint is?

Comment: sorry @FiddleStix I found that the problem was simply r at the beginning of the address.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I just added r at the beginning of the address.
$ means that it is a hidden directory.

\ wihtout r at the beginning is always a problem not in case of having $ in the address.

workplace = (r"\147.134.45.32\d$\output\mil\" + folder + "/")

if not os.path.exists(workplace):
    os.mkdir(workplace)